# Creating a makefile with dependencies

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to understand makefile.  I have the following files:

```
main.c
(includes progA.c progB.c progC.c)

progA.c
(includes progA.h)

progB.c
(includes progA.c)

progC.c
```

I've tried to create a makefile, but not sure if it's correct or not:

```
main.o: main.c progA.o progB.o progC.o
    gcc -c main.c

progA.o: progA.c progB.o
    gcc -c progA.c

progB.o: progB.c progB.h
    gcc -c progB.c

progC.o: progC.c 
    gcc -c progC.c
```

Can somebody please help me to understand.  I've tried to look at tutorials, but there's different information given.

Also, how can I actually run this to test?

Comment: Save the file as `makefile`, to run use `make` command.

Comment: In what way does `progB.c` includes `progA.c`?

Comment: progB.c uses one of progA.c functions

Comment: You're using "includes" incorrectly which will be a source of confusion.  "Includes" has a very specific meaning in programming.  What you want to say is that main.c _references_ progA.c, or more exactly, it references functions from progA.c.  Source files _include_ header files, by using the `#include` directive.  Source files virtually never _include_ other source files; instead each source file is compiled separately then _linked_ together into a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, the following makefile should do the job. You can run the makefile by simply typing `make` or `make -f <name_of_makefile>` if your makefile has a custom name (e.g. `build_main`)

```
all: main

main: main.o progA.o progB.o progC.o
    gcc -o main main.o progA.o progB.o progC.o

main.o: main.c     
    gcc -c main.c   

progA.o: progA.c
    gcc -c progA.c

progB.o: progB.c
    gcc -c progB.c

progC.o: procC.c
    gcc -c progC.c
```

To build the executable, the objects `main.o progA.o progB.o progC.o` are necessary as specified in the line after `main:`.

The rules for compiling`main.o progA.o progB.o` and `progC.o` are given by the following four sections.

The general format of a makefile is

```
target: dependencies
[tab] system command
```

Answer (score 0):

this look strange:

```
progA.o: progA.c progB.o
  gcc -c progA.c
```

normally a makefile-"line" has three components:

- target: this should be the result of the execution of the command line. One traget is the special target, namely the first; typically this is called "all" and dependeces the main target (the executable file for example)
- dependencies: this are all files that are used to create the target in the command line, explicit like the source file end implicit like #include files
- command line: the command to create the target from the depentant files